# PHP How to remove =20 from multiple lines

Tags: php, regex, replace

I am wondering if it is possible to remove only =20 from the end of multiple lines within a block of text?  This is for my e-mail to ticket gateway.  When a reply is received and contains multiple "=20" I want to remove them.  However I want to leave =20 intact if it is legitimately part an e-mail (such as a URL).  An example of an incoming e-mail:

```
$correspondence = <<<EOF
Hello=20
=20
Thank you for getting back to me.=20
The link you need is http://domain.com/index.php?id=204726 .=20
Regards=20
EOF;
```

Comment: how do you know if it is part of a url? I wouldn't assume it is part of the url you have in your example. `.=20` after a url doesn't seem like part of the url to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is [quoted-printable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quoted-printable) encoding, which uses `=` followed by hex codes to encode special characters in plain text. Use [`quoted_printable_decode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.quoted-printable-decode.php) to decode a message that's encoded this way. You shouldn't have to worry about literal `=20` anywhere in the text, because it should be encoded as `=3D20` (`=3D` is the encoding for the `=` sign), and you'll get back the original `=20` when it's decoded.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using the discard technique with a regex like this:

```
http://.*=20$(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|=20
```

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/fR7gE2/1)**

The idea behind this regex is to discard what matches the `(*SKIP)(*FAIL)` and to keep the `=20`. So, for your case above regex will discard the links.

You can see in the `Substitution` section the expected output.

[image]

The php code:

```
$re = "/http.*=20$(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|=20/m"; 
$str = "\$correspondence = <<<EOF\nHello=20\n=20\nThank you for getting back to me.=20\nThe link you need is http://domain.com/index.php?id=204726 .=20\nRegards=20\nEOF;"; 
$subst = ""; 

$result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str);
```